# PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore not writing to file

Tags: spring-integration

I am using SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter and SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter along with metadata store. But I noticed that it is not flushing the entries to file. I never show flush() method being called from PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore which ultimately invokes saveMetaData() method.

Here is my config looks like

```
<bean id="compositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg value="*.txt" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg name="store" ref="metadataStore"/>
                <constructor-arg value="myapp"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean name="metadataStore" class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore">
    <property name="baseDirectory" value="/tmp/"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` flushes to the file on  `applicationContext` destroy:

```
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    flush();
}

@Override
public void flush() {
    saveMetadata();
}

@Override
public void destroy() throws Exception {
    flush();
}
```

Starting with `4.1.2` you can invoke `flush()` manually at runtime.
E.g. periodically with `<task:sheduled-tasks>` or with some `<int:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

Feel free to ask for more information!